# RIGHT() function in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Can I implement the following in SQLAlchemy,

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE RIGHT(COLUMN_CODE, 2) = 'AX'
```

here `RIGHT( )` returns the right part of a character string with the specified number of characters.

Is there a SQLAlchemy implementation of the `RIGHT` function?

Comment: Do you mean `RIGHT(COLUMN_CODE,2)` should return the last two characters of the string?

Comment: Yes ... But I am trying to use it in where condition

something like,

query.filter(right(coulumn_code,2)== 'AX')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd be better off using the `.endswith()` method instead:

```
select([tabledef]).where(tabledef.c.column_code.endswith('AX'))
```

or, when filtering with a mapper config and a session:

```
session.query(mappedobject).filter(mappedobject.column_code.endswith('AX'))
```

The `column_code.endswith()` method will be translated to whatever SQL is best for your particular engine, matching column values that end with `AX`.

You can always use the [function generator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/expression_api.html?highlight=function#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func) to create arbitrary SQL functions if you *have* to use the `RIGHT()` sql function directly:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func

select([tabledef]).where(func.right(tabledef.c.column_code, 2) == 'AX')
```

and the `func.right()` call will be translated to `RIGHT(column_code, 2)` by the SQL generation layer.

Comment: Using `func.right()` rather than `endswith()` also allows to chain with other operators, for instance `.in_()`, which is quite useful to filter a substring of the column from a list rather than from a scalar  `func.right(tabledef.c.column_code, 2).in_(['AX', 'BX'])`

Answer (score 2):

The documentation does not make it clear, but you can write *any* function using `func.funcname` sytle. `funcname` does not have to be defined natively by SQLAlchemy module. SQLAlchemy knows about common functions like min, max etc. and if there is dialect to dialect variation amongst those functions, SQLAlchemy takes care of that for you.

But the functions that SQLAlchemy does not know about are passed *as is*. So you can create your query that generates a SQL statement with the required `RIGHT` function like so

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import func
>>> select([table]).where(func.RIGHT(users.c.column_code, 2)='AX')
```

Comment: for logic checks you'd need to have '==' in sqlalchemy